# List Import Error: Invalid Context Status

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, import

I am trying to import a list of about 400,000 records into a list. Upon completion of the upload, I only get 2k records imported with the rest returning an "Invalid Context Status" and failing. Would appreciate advise on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong. Initially the list was 2.2M long and I chose to go with the automatic mapping suggested by the wizard. This imported about 1.7 M customers and failed on the remainder. To get the remaining 400k records through, I had to clear all the recommended mapping and manually map the required field. I suspect the automatic mapping might have failed because of null values in the optional field.

Comment: Typically this error is from trying to import subscribers with a status field value that isn't 'Active' or 'Unsubscribed'. You can't upload subscribers with a 'Bounced' or 'Held' status. Not sure if this was the case for you, but it's the only time I've seen it come up.

Comment: Makes sense! @AnonWonderer  which is why I had to unmap "status"

Comment: Thank you so much @AnonWonderer - this was indeed our issue. We were pulling out our hair trying to reliably reproduce the issue! You should post this as an alternate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Posting as an alternate answer as requested:

Typically this error is from trying to import subscribers with a status field value that isn't 'Active' or 'Unsubscribed'. You can't upload subscribers with a 'Bounced' or 'Held' status. Not sure if this was the case for you, but it's the only time I've seen it come up.

Comment: This wasn't the issue, but it makes sense why this would also cause it!